# How can I email myself the RAW SQL query that this php function is producing?

Tags: php, sql, performance, debugging, invision-power-board

I want to run explain on a query that is slow but I don't know how to view the raw sql so I can run it in phpmyadmin and debug it. Here is the function.

```
    private function getAttImages($limit, $forumIds = 0, $fidsReverse = false, $topicIds = 0, $membersIds = 0, $order = 'attach_date', $sort = 'desc', $group = null)
{
    $fids = '';

    if ($forumIds)
    {
        $r = '';
        if ($fidsReverse)
        {
            $r = ' NOT ';
        }

        if (is_array($forumIds))
        {
            $forumIds = implode(',', $forumIds);
        }

        $fids = ' AND forums_topics.forum_id ' . $r . ' IN (' . $forumIds .  ')';
    }

    $tids = '';
    if ($topicIds)
    {
        $tids = ' AND forums_topics.tid IN (' . $topicIds . ')';
    }

    $mids = '';
    if ($membersIds)
    {
        $mids = ' AND core_attachments.attach_member_id IN (' . $membersIds . ')';
    }


    $whereT = array();
    $joinsT = array();

    $findInPosts = ' AND ' . \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('queued', array('0'));
    $joinsT[] = array(
                        'select'    => 'forums_posts.*',
                        'from'      => 'forums_posts',
                        'where'     => array("forums_posts.pid=core_attachments_map.id2" . $findInPosts),
                );

    $findInTopics = ' AND ' . \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('approved', array('1'));
    $joinsT[] = array(
                        'select'    => 'forums_topics.*',
                        'from'      => 'forums_topics',
                        'where'     => array("forums_topics.tid=forums_posts.topic_id" . $findInTopics . $fids . $tids),
                );

    $select = 'core_attachments.attach_id AS custom_data, core_attachments.*';
    if ($group)
    {
        $select = 'core_attachments.attach_id AS custom_data, COUNT(attach_is_image) as cnt_images, SUM(attach_hits) as summ_attach_hits, core_attachments.*';
    }

    $joinsT[] = array(
                        'select'    => $select,
                        'from'      => 'core_attachments',
                        'where'     => array('core_attachments.attach_is_image=1 AND core_attachments.attach_is_archived=0 AND core_attachments.attach_id=core_attachments_map.attachment_id' . $mids),

                );              

    $joinsT[] = array(  'select'    => 'core_members.member_id, core_members.member_group_id, core_members.mgroup_others, core_members.name, core_members.members_seo_name',
                        'from'      => 'core_members',
                        'where'     => array('core_attachments.attach_member_id=core_members.member_id' . $mids),
                );

    $joinsT[] = array(  'select'    => 'core_permission_index.perm_id',
                        'from'      => 'core_permission_index',
                        'where'     => array("core_permission_index.app='forums' AND core_permission_index.perm_type='forum' AND core_permission_index.perm_type_id=forums_topics.forum_id"),
                );

    $groupT = $group;

    $whereT[] = array(
        "core_attachments_map.location_key='forums_Forums' AND " . 
        \IPS\Db::i()->findInSet('perm_view', array_merge(array(\IPS\Member::loggedIn()->member_group_id), array_filter(explode(',', \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->mgroup_others)))) . " OR perm_view='*'" .
        $fids . $tids . $mids
    );

    $table = new \IPS\Helpers\Table\Db(
        'core_attachments_map',
        \IPS\Http\Url::internal('app=core&module=system&controller=nbattachpictures', 'front', 'nbattachpictures'),
        $whereT,
        $groupT
    );

    $table->joins = $joinsT;
    $table->sortBy = $order;
    $table->sortDirection = $sort;
    $table->limit = $limit;

    $table->rowsTemplate = array(\IPS\Theme::i()->getTemplate('plugins', 'core', 'global'), 'nbAttachmentsBlocksRows');

    $table->parsers = array(
        'custom_data' => function( $val, $row )
        {
            return array(
                'topic_data' => \IPS\Http\Url::internal("app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id={$row['tid']}", 'front', 'forums_topic', array($row['title_seo'])),
                'summ_attach_hits' => $row['summ_attach_hits'],
                'jewel' => $this->attachJewel($row['summ_attach_hits']),
            );
        },
    );

    return $table;
}
```

Anybody know how I can see the SQL query only that is produced by this function? email is better than echo as I want to grab query from live site.

Comment: which framework? you will have to dig in to it

Comment: Invision Power board 4

Comment: your are mostly gong to have to do the digging yourself, unless your really lucky and some one here knows it well

Comment: I was hoping there was a  way to collect the parts of the sql statements as this runs and then email the result to myself. no?

Comment: your could email `$table`, if you think that's going to help

Comment: Table is an array I believe, so I think I would have to foreach on it some how

Comment: `$maiL_this=print_r($table,1);`

Comment: well it gave me output but it's not SQL. . it's all the components of the entire set of arrays in table. man.. ugh

Comment: well i told you that beofre

Answer (score 1):

You could `var_dump($table)` and write the result in an email using the native php `mail` function or write it in a log file (this option is better).

Is that framework open-source? Because I couldn't find any documentation about the class `\IPS\Helpers\Table\Db`. Probably there's a method in it to build the query, you could look for it at that class source code and put the result of that method into the email message or log file instead of var_dump the table.

Comment: yeah it's open source. Their documentation isn't the best

Comment: I think that's not the class we need to take a look. The class you passed was `\IPS\Db`, we need `\IPS\Helpers\Table\Db`.

Comment: Is there a Multiton Store class on namespace `\IPS`? From the helper class, we can see that the line 330 is where the query is executed. It calls the static method `i()` on the class `\IPS\Db`, which returns a Multiton Store. Then it's called that object's `select` method. And this can keep going on and on, so you'll have to look at the source code to see where this goes.

Comment: it's overwhelming isn't it? Shezzz...this is why I couldn't figure it out. All I want to do is run an explain so I can speed this thing up. Thanks for your help just the same.

Comment: It seems that you can use the `query` method of the `\IPS\Db` class, but you'd needed to turn the attribute `$returnQuery` to true and scan the file I didn't find anything yet. One way you could solve this is following the trail I said before, or even debugging if you have xdebug configured.